# How to prevent this light banding issue when using EffectsComposer?

Tags: three.js

I have a simple scene with a plane and a spotlight which works fine with standard renderer but the light becomes banded when using composer. In this example I'm using a bloompass with 0.001 strength. The same effect happens with other passes such as LUT. - What is happening here and how to retain the light 'quality' when using composer?

With standard renderer:

[image]

With composer:

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please try to create the composer with a custom render target using `THREE.HalfFloatType` as the render target's type? Something like `new EffectComposer( renderer, new WebGLRenderTarget( width, height, { type: THREE.HalfFloatType ) );`

Comment: Scratch my other comment, you are correct - that has resolved the issue! Is this performant however, there's a couple mentions of issues of performance in a similar context here -- https://discourse.threejs.org/t/bloom-and-anti-aliasing-banding/22399/2 ? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Mugen87's comment the solution was to include a render target with HalfFloatType -

```
composer = new EffectComposer(
    renderer, 
    new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
        window.innerWidth, 
        window.innerHeight, 
        { type: THREE.HalfFloatType }
    ) );
```

Comment: As long as we support WebGL 1, we are not going to change the default render target type from `THREE.UnsignedByteType`. At least it is the current policy. However, with WebGL 1 support removed in the future, `EffectComposer` will handle this more gracefully.